# jQuery / JS - Detecting / Matching an URL string to determine it's type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two URLs types, (TYPE A)

```
/items
```

Or /items/XXXX with a trailing number (TYPE B)

```
/items/187
/items/12831
```

I would like to know how to detect if the URL is type A or Type B

```
if (TYPE A) ... else if (TYPE B) ....
```

Any suggestions for making this happen? Do I need a regex?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for the check, for example:

```
if(/\/items\/\d+/.test(url)) {
  //type B
} else if (/\/items/.test(url)) {
  //type A
}
```

This checks for the number version first, if that fails it checks for at least `/items`...if you're assured it's one or the other you can leave off the second `if` and just use the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `pathname` on `/`, and do a `parseInt()` on the last item in the Array.

```
if( parseInt( location.pathname.split('/').pop() ) ) {
    // was a successful number, so type B
} else {
    // was NaN, so type A
}
```

If it was successfully parsed as a number, it was type B, otherwise, type A.

Note that this will fail if you have the number `0` for the number. If `0` is a possibility, then you could just add `1` to the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (type == '/items'){
  // Type A
} else if (type.match('/\/items\/[0-9]+/')){
  //Type B
} else {
  //Not either of the two
}
```

You can just match the string for the first part, the 2nd part could require regex if you need a third condition, otherwise, it's

```
if (type == '/items'){
  //A
} else {
  //B, (or anything else)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// /items/1233
if (url.match('\\/items/\\d+'))
{

}
// /items/
else if (url.match('\\/items/'))
{

}
```

Comment: This `\d+` requires a regular expression, which means you'll need to either do `'\\/items\\/\\d+'` or `/\/items\/\d+/`. (You're missing the closing `)` for your `if()` statements too.)